# Why does test method not complete in azure devops build pipeline, dotnet test task

Tags: c#, testing, .net-core, moq, xunit

I am running a dotnet test task in my azure devops build pipeline.

The test completes fine in Visual Studio (16.4.3) IDE on my machine, also using CLI with the "dotnet test" command.

However, in azure it fails. My solution is a .NET Core 3.1 API. The test returns a `CreatedAtRouteResult` type on a controller test. And I am asserting `IsType<CreatedAtRouteResult>`. Though in Azure it returns a `ObjectResult` and not the expected `CreatedAtRouteResult`. Additional info, test project is using xUnit and Moq. Though these frameworks are not related to the error.

I am not able to navigate to the build folder on the agents used in our private cloud.

[Test code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTJHV.png)

Results from the test in Visual Studio and using dotnet test in CLI

[Results from tests in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSAgq.png)

Developer CLI, using "dotnet test"

> Test run for
>   ...\SqlViewService.Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\SqlViewService.Tests.dll(.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1)
>   Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.3.0
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Starting test execution, please wait...
>
> A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
>
> Test Run Successful. Total tests: 10
>        Passed: 10  Total time: 15,0151 Seconds
>
> ...\SqlViewService.Tests>

The error code from the azure build task:

> [Error message on dotnet test task in azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oY2P.png)

I am following this link to setup the pipeline, though I am not using YAML but the GUI build pipeline tasks. Like so:

[Test task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDfY0.png)

Publish looks like this:

[Publish task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpP1Z.png)

Test execution command line tool version is 16.3.0 in both azure task and locally.

Pretty basic setup, however cannot figure out where the mismatch appears. Do you have any idea or solution?

I have been looking into this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops

As requested in comment, method under test:

```
 public IActionResult UpdateView([FromBody] SqlViewModel sqlView, [FromHeader, Required] int correlationId, DateTime date)
        {
            try
            {
                ThreadContext.Properties["RunID"] = correlationId;
                ThreadContext.Properties["Username"] = Environment.UserName;

                _logger.LogInformation("SQL View Model: " + sqlView.Name + ", " + sqlView.Database + ", " +
                                       sqlView.UsePrecedingWorkdayLogic);
                foreach (var sourceInfo in sqlView.Sources)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Table Info: " + sourceInfo.Name + ", " + sourceInfo.SearchString + ", " +
                                           sourceInfo.DateFormat);
                }

                ViewLogic.SetViewDate(sqlView, date);
                //Returns the location in the response header
                return CreatedAtRoute("GetView", new { view = sqlView.Name }, sqlView);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Database failure: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: There should be a tab called "Tests".  It should by default filter to failed tests.  Does it have any additional information like stack trace that might be useful to troubleshoot the failure?

Comment: Show the `UpdateView()` method

Comment: @haim770 method included. Let me know if you see anything here or let me know if you have any idea, why this succeed fine in visual studio and using dotnet test locally. But not in my azure build pipeline.

Comment: @Matt, I see no other stacktrace than the one you also see in the image under "Error on dotnet test task in azure"

Comment: `ObjectResult` is being returned when the `StatusCode()` method is invoked. And in your code it's being used when you `catch` an exception. It seems like you do have some database (or mocked-database) failure when your code runs in Azure Pipelines. For a start, I would change my test code to print the value that is associated with the returned `ObjectResult`

Comment: Remove `try .. catch`, if exception will be raised 500 Response will be returned anyway. But provide better guidance in your current problem.

Comment: @haim770, I think you are onto something, I have been locating a small bug in my regex used in the view logic. However, removing that bug did not change the behaviour in azure. My working theory at the moment is that the actual update (alter) statement I am running on the SQL view does is not allowed (by "unknown"-user executing test task in azure). Despite that I have a test method doing a select query on the same view and a reads the definition, which succeed fine in both azure and locally.

Comment: @Fabio, I am catching various exceptions here thrown in BLL and/or DAL, as the snippet you see are still part of development, I will assure you that I am not going to be showing the exception here at the endpoint, rather logging it to my DB. But I will attempt your suggestion and see if I get any additional info I can use.